# Structured data Mining from OCR data into the database of specific fields without using template

Tags: ocr

I need help with specific field data extraction from ID OCR extracted data. Like name, address etc. I want to make an algorithm that can extract this specific data using training data and insert into the database without using a specific template. Any help is kindly appreciated. Looking forward to hearing from you.
Thamks